# Xpages: how to use viewEnt.getColumnValues() to retrieve all relevant value when export data?

Tags: xpages, data-retrieval

In the Xpage, it will display officer name, officer type and department (I use sessionScope variable to do that). There is a `combobox` to allow the user to select 
the officer type that the user wants to compare. And then a button is used for export the data.

The export data will show the comparison between the document that the selected officer type needs to read and the document that the current officer has been read. 
If the officer has read document that matches the selected officer type needs to read, it will show "Document has been read", otherwise, it will 
show "Document has not read"

Due this post [export data from panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23678540/export-data-from-panel?noredirect=1&lq=1) let me know how to export data from panel, I begin to follow the code from the post and modify some code to fulfill the user requirement.

I have two views to do the comparison:

Each officer type needs to read various documents, so there is a view to store the value, the first column is the officer type and the second column is the document 
that the officer type should read. The second column is multi value field and I am able to set the Multi-value separator is New Line.

Another view the includes officer name, the related officer type and document read by the officer.(no column for multi value)

I use `@DbLookup` and ***`for`*** loop to do the comparison and here is part of code:

```
var officer = sessionScope.Officer;
var officerType = sessionScope.OfficerType;
var showSelectedTypeDoc = @DbLookup(@DbName(),"view1", officerType, 2); 
var showUserHasReadDoc= @DbLookup(@DbName(),"view2", officer, 3); 
var result = "";

while (viewEnt != null)
{
    if(viewEnt.getColumnValues()[1] == officer) //get the value related to the officer in the session
    { 
        writer.write("<tr>");
        for(var s = 0; s < showSelectedTypeDoc.length;s++) //loop in view1 first
        {
            for(var r = 0; r < showUserHasReadDoc.length;r++)//then loop the  view2
            {
                if(showSelectedTypeDoc[s] == showUserHasReadDoc[r])//if value matches between 2 views
                 {
                     result = "Document has been read";
                 }
                else
                {
                   result = "Document has not read";
                }
            }
        }
      //display the list of the document category related to specific officer type
        writer.write("<td>" +  viewEnt.getColumnValues()[2] + "</td>"); //Problem occurs here, it only shows the first value, the appearance depends on the loop
        writer.write("<td>" + result+ "</td>"); // only display the else part 
        writer.write("</tr>");
    }
}
```

Actually I suppose

```
viewEnt.getColumnValues()[2]
```

will show all the relevant values, however when I export the value, it only display the first value e.g. [first value]. 
The code

```
 writer.write("<td>" + result+ "</td>");
```

I review the if condition, it should be fine, but it only shows the else part

I tried

```
showSelectedTypeDoc[s]
```

instead of

```
viewEnt.getColumnValues()[2]
```

it shows undefined and the appearance depends on the looping.

But if I try

```
showSelectedTypeDoc[0] //or showSelectedTypeDoc[1], etc
```

it can show the correct value and the appearance depends on the looping.

However I will not know how many values that the variable stored, so I prefer

```
showSelectedTypeDoc[s]
```

to find all relevant values but not successful.

I start to think why it only shows the first value. I revise the code and the view, I guess probably is the multi value column cause the problem. It is because In Louts Client, in the view I only click once to particular value, if the value has multi value, it will show the "tick" symbol to relevant data.

So I would like to know to how to use

```
viewEnt.getColumnValues()[2]
```

to retrieve all the data related to a specific value. Grateful for your advice please. Thank you.

Comment: In `writer.write("<td>" +  viewEnt.getColumnValues()[2] + "</td>");`, I have tried `writer.write("<td>" + showSelectedTypeDoc.length + "</td>");`. It can show the correct length in the view.

Comment: But if I try `writer.write("<td>" + showSelectedTypeDoc + "</td>");`, when I export the data, it shows strange result. It display `<<<<<` and the location is not match to the relevant column.

Comment: I read this post [Beware of what getColumnValue is returning](http://linqed.eu/2010/08/16/beware-of-what-getcolumnvalue-is-returning/). I applied the code in the application, when I export the data, the result is empty.

Comment: I would like to ask does the code `getColumnValue(“column”)`, means the column name in the view?  Does the column need to categorized?

Answer (score 1):

`getColumnsValues()` returns a Java Vector. So the syntax you need to get a specific element in the Vector is `getColumnValues().get(2)` (which will get the third column).

Getting a column values doesn't need it to be categorised. Categorisation is only required for retrieving the entry, not the column values.

I believe when using the index that static columns (e.g. with formula set to a static value like `1` or `"<tr>"`) are skipped.

Comment: A couple of additional points to bear in mind, once you have it working.
1) @DbLookup is the least performant method of getting an entry. Formula language may be quickest in Notes Client, but in XPages it needs to route through to an underlying Java function (`View.getAllEntriesByKey()`) and each parameter needs parsing and converting. It's best to go directly to `getAllEntriesByKey()`.
2) View entries should be recycled while looping. There are various questions and blog posts on this. Also, if the view includes date columns, the `getColumnValues()` object should also be recycled.

Comment: Paul is absolutely right. Your current approach does a @DbLookup for each row in the table. Not a good idea. Do one lookup using getAllEntriesByKey once, load the unids into a JS object and compare that